# Delete Data From a Specific Row in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

What is the best way to delete a row of data in Core Data? I can find a lot of answers online with indexPath like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[self managedObjectContext];
[context deleteObject:[self.recordarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSError *error=nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Cant save %@ %@",error,[error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self.recordarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I don't have a Table View , I am saving data for a Custom View. I am very new to Core data, basically I want to do something like that in SQL

```
Delete Row with FirstColumn(Primary Key) is Equal to "ABC"
```

Can someone help me and provide a link.

Comment: I assume you have the core data object in your view ? So just delete that .. [context deleteObject:YOU_CORE_DATA_OBJECT]; Then do the save ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing a specific entry/row from Core-Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524876/removing-a-specific-entry-row-from-core-data)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38459233/5461400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data will be stored in an core data object just delete that object.
Also can also refer

[Delete object in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039575/delete-object-in-core-data)

[Removing a specific entry/row from Core-Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524876/removing-a-specific-entry-row-from-core-data)

Hope this will resolve your query.

Comment: These should be duplicate flags / links

Answer (score 2):

Like Sqlite's "DELETE from tableName WHERE condition", you have no single step to delete `MULTIPLE` objects from CoreData.

In **CoreData**, first you have to **fetch** objects that has to be deleted, using `NSFetchRequest` and `NSPredicate`

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyName == %@", value];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;//Your ManagedObjectContext;
NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Then, you should **iterate** through every `NSManagedObject` and call `deleteObject:` from your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
if (!error && result.count > 0) {
    for(NSManagedObject *managedObject in result){
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    }

    //Save context to write to store
    [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```