# delete and Update Data in Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi i am a newbie in Core Data in iOS, I have implemented a 4 textfields namely name,age,company,address. Now when the user enter the data i am saving the data in Core Data.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context =
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject *newContact;
newContact = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newContact setValue: _name.text forKey:@"name"];
[newContact setValue: _address.text forKey:@"address"];
[newContact setValue: _age.text forKey:@"age"];
[newContact setValue:_company.text forKey:@"company
```

Similarly i am able to fetch and display the Data in these textfields.

AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context =
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc =
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device"
            inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name = %@)",
 _name.text];
[request setPredicate:pred];
NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                          error:&error];matches = objects[0];

    _address.text = [matches valueForKey:@"address"];
    _age.text = [matches valueForKey:@"age"];
    _company.text = [matches valueForKey:@"company"];
```

Now while i want to delete  and Update the data of the particular User i am not able to fetch the data.

How can i delete the data and Update ..?

I have gone through this link
http://www.appcoda.com/core-data-tutorial-update-delete/

Thank in Advance

Comment: As suggested in the tutorial delete and update the data in the main view controller rather than in the detail view controller.

Comment: That tutorial just a reference

Comment: can you create a nsobject file to achieve it simply. and reuse again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can delete data like :

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entityname" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID like %@",userID];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items)
    {
        [context deleteObject:managedObject];
    }
```

and for Update :

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entityname" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID like %@",userID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *arrResult = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
YourEntityname *entity = arrResult[0];
entity.userID = @"2"
[appdelegate saveContext];
```

Answer (score 4):

For updating NSManagedObject first you need to get object from fetch array and change value of this object and save again

```
NSError *error;              
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {

     NSLog(@"%@",[error1 localizedDescription]);

}
else
{
     NSLog(@"save Successfully");               
}
```

for delete

```
[[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:<#(nonnull NSManagedObject *)#>]
```

pass your NSManage object you want to delete

**Swift 3 :-**

Create Records.

Person entity with two attribute name, number.

```
let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: manageObjectContext) as! Person
person.name = "<#name string#>"
person.number = "<#number string#>"
do {
   try manageObjectContext.save()
}
catch {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Fetch Record

```
  var Per = [Person]()

  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
  do {
      Per = try manageObjectContext().fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Person]
  } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
```

Update Records

```
ler person = per[0] 
person.name = "<#name string#>"
person.number = "<#number string#>"
do {
   try manageObjectContext.save()
}
catch {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Delete Records:

```
let person = per[0]

self.manageObjectContext().delete(person)

do {
     try manageObjectContext().save()
}
catch {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 func Update(name: String , address : String , mobile : String , email : String , imgs : NSString) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: managedContext)!
     //let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "entity")

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")

        do {
            let array_users = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let people = array_users[0] as NSManagedObject

            //let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

            people.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")
            people.setValue(address, forKeyPath: "address")
            people.setValue(imgs, forKeyPath: "img")
            people.setValue(email, forKeyPath: "mailid")
            people.setValue(mobile, forKeyPath: "mobile")                //save the context
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                print("saved!")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            } catch {

            }

        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For delete the object in core data you can use this code:
Pass the name of entity which you want to delete...

```
-(void)deleteAllObjects: (NSString *)entityName{
    NSFetchRequest *request=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *items =[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    }
    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error deleting: %@ - error: %@",entityName,error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you have create the Entity with Attributes. [image: Reference Image]
2. Example TripLog is an Entity and attributes are date,startLat,startLong,endLat,endLatitude.
3. Create an NSManagement File TripLog. h and TripLog. m

   TripLog.h contains declaration of variable with @property.
    TripLog.m contains implementation of variables.
4. Create Category file for TripLog (Addition).
5. Create NSObject file to make a operation the selectData,updateData,DeleteData.

   Entity File: Code Snap 
   TripLog.h

   ```
   @interface TripLog : NSManagedObject

   @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *date;
   @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *startLatitude;
   @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *startLongitude;
   @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *endLatitude;
   @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *endLongitude;
   @property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *distance;
   @end
   ```

   TripLog.m

   ```
   @implementation TripLog

   @dynamic date;
   @dynamic startLatitude;
   @dynamic startLongitude;
   @dynamic endLatitude;
   @dynamic endLongitude;
   @dynamic distance;

   @end
   ```

   Category File :code Snap

   TripLog+Addition.h

   ```
   #import "TripLog.h"

   @interface TripLog (Addition)

   + (TripLog *)indexWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

   @end
   ```

   TripLog+Addition.m

   ```
   #import "TripLog+Addition.h"

   @implementation TripLog (Addition)


   + (TripLog *)indexWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
   {
   TripLog *indexValues      = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TripLog"
                                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];

   indexValues.date      = [dict valueForKey:@"date"];
   indexValues.startLatitude   = [dict valueForKey:@"startLatitude"];
   indexValues.startLongitude  = [dict valueForKey:@"startLongitude"];
   indexValues.endLatitude     = [dict valueForKey:@"endLatitude"];
   indexValues.endLongitude    = [dict valueForKey:@"endLongitude"];
   indexValues.distance        = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[dict valueForKey:@"distance"]doubleValue]];



   return indexValues;
   }
   @end
   ```

   NSObjectFile : DataManager

   ```
    #import "TripLog.h"

    @protocol DataManagerDelegate;
    @interface DataManager : NSObject{

    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIManagedDocument *dataDocument;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <DataManagerDelegate> delegate;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) TripLog *tripLog;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel   * managedObjectModel;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
    + (DataManager *)sharedInstance;
    -(void)saveTripLogDetails:(NSDictionary *)tripLogDict;
    - (void)updateTripLog:(NSDictionary *)tripLogDict;
    - (void)deleteTripLog:(id)object;
    -(NSArray *)getTripLogDetails;
    @end
    @protocol DataManagerDelegate <NSObject>
    @optional
    - (void)didFinishSaving:(DataManager *)dataManager;
    @end
   ```

   Datamanager.m file

   ```
   #import "DataManager.h" 
   #import "AppDelegate.h"
   #import "TripLog+Addition.h"

   @interface DataManager ()

    - (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification;
   @end

   @implementation DataManager

   @synthesize dataDocument;
   @synthesize delegate;

   @synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
   @synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
   @synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

   #pragma mark - SharedInstance

   + (DataManager *)sharedInstance
    {
     static DataManager *sharedInstance = nil;
     static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
     dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       sharedInstance = [[DataManager alloc] init];
     });
     return sharedInstance;
    }

     - (id)init {
      self = [super init];

      if (self) {

       // Initialise the classe
       // Create the Core Data document
       NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                            inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
       url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Gridz.sqlite"];

       self.dataDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Gridz.sqlite"];


       if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
           [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
       }



       // Set our document up for automatic migrations
       NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
       self.dataDocument.persistentStoreOptions = options;

       [self setupDocument];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
                                                    name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                  object:self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];


   }
   return self;
   }



    - (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    }


    #pragma mark - Context Notification Methods

    - (void)objectsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
     NSLog(@"NSManagedObjects did change.");

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
                                                name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                              object:self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];

    }

    - (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
    NSlog(@"NSManagedContext did save.");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                 object:self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];

   if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishSaving:)]) {
       [delegate didFinishSaving:self];
   }
   }
   #pragma mark - Setup Document

   - (void)setupDocument {

   if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.dataDocument.fileURL path]]) {
   LOG(@"does not exist on disk, so create it");
   // does not exist on disk, so create it
   [self.dataDocument saveToURL:self.dataDocument.fileURL
               forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
              completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

              }];
   } else if (self.dataDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
   LOG(@"exists on disk, but we need to open it");
   // exists on disk, but we need to open it
   [self.dataDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

   }];
   } else if (self.dataDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
   LOG(@"UIDocumentStateNormal");
   }
   }
   -(void)saveTripLogDetails:(NSDictionary *)tripLogDict
   {
   self.tripLog =[TripLog indexWithDictionary:tripLogDict inManagedObjectContext:self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];

   }
   - (void)deleteTripLog:(id)object {
    if (object)
    {
     [self.dataDocument. managedObjectContext deleteObject: indexObject];
           }
    }
      -(NSArray *)getTripLogDetails{
      NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSEntityDescription *entity  = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TripLog"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];
      NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];

     fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

     [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
     NSError *error = nil;
     NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
      return fetchedObjects;
    }    

     -(void)updateTripLog :(NSMutableDictionary *)dict
    {

      NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSEntityDescription *entity  = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TripLog"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext];

       NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

       fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((date== %@))",[dict valueForKey:@"date"]];
       fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

       [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects =    [self.dataDocument.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

       if([fetchedObjects count]>0){
       TripLog *indexValues = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

       indexValues.date      = [dict valueForKey:@"date"];
       indexValues.startLatitude   = [dict valueForKey:@"startLatitude"];
       indexValues.startLongitude  = [dict valueForKey:@"startLongitude"];
       indexValues.endLatitude     = [dict valueForKey:@"endLatitude"];
       indexValues.endLongitude    = [dict valueForKey:@"endLongitude"];
       indexValues.distance        = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[dict valueForKey:@"distance"]doubleValue]];


   }else
      [self saveTripLogDetails:dict]; //insert Dictionary
    }
   ```

   @end

   Use the DataManger File in the Viewcontroller

   1. ## import "TripLog.h" text in top
   2. In viewDidLoad

      ```
       NSArray *tripDetails = [[DataManager sharedInstance] getTripDetails];
       TripLog *tribLog = [tripDetails objectAtIndex:0];
       NSLog(@"TripDate:%@",tribLog.date);
       [[DataManager sharedInstance]deleteTripDetails:tribLog]; //delete the tripDetails
      ```