# Updating an Existing Core Data Entry

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi fellow developers,

I have an app in its early stages utilising Core Data.

The premise is simple: Add in restaurants, save it to Core Data and display it. So I have an `AddEntry` with a bunch of `textFields` - the user fills those in, clicks `Save` and it gets saved to Core Data. In the main view, the data gets displayed using `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UITableViewController`. That works well.

I have a `DetailView` which looks exactly like the `AddEntry` and is a segue away from the `Timeline`; click a cell and it goes to a `DetailView` displaying all of the information populated in.

I'm trying to edit entry here, by for example, changing the name of the food, or the restaurant (`textFields`) and save it to Core Data. Saving works, but what I've realised is that it actually doesn't override the entry, it just creates a brand new entry.

I totally understand why it's doing that - I'm creating a new instance, etc, but I'm not 100% sure what to do.

In a previous app, I used a technique to:

- perform a fetch request
- create an array of fetchRequets
- if the entry doesn't exist, create it
- if it does, return it.

That code (written in Objective C) is below:

Person *person = nil;

```
// Creating a fetch request to check whether the person already exists, calling from the Add/DetailViewController.
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", name];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *people = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (!people)
{
    // Handle Error
}
else if (![people count])
{
    // If the person count is 0 then create it
    person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    person.name = name;
}
else
{
    // If the object exists, just return it
    person = [people lastObject];
}
return person;
```

I'm now doing this new application in Swift, and I'm wondering:

- is this the right approach? To fetch request, create new entry if it doesn't exist, or return it if it does?
- In my Save code, I don't seem to have "`insertNewObjectForEntityForName`" as part of my new Swift code - am I missing that?

Here's my "save" code.

```
if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {


        // I am creating an instance of both the food and restaurant from the Food and Restaurant Managed Objects.
        foodEntry = FoodManagedObject(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        restaurantEntry = RestaurantsManagedObject(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        foodEntry.nameOfFood = foodTextField.text
        appDelegate.saveContext()
        print("the food name is \(String(describing: foodEntry.nameOfFood))")
    }
```

Any thoughts are welcomed.

**Update**

The answer provided the information I needed to get this working, but for my own understanding, I need to figure out something and see if I can understand what's going on.

In the video provided and the other solutions, when adding a new entry to CoreData, the code `insertNewObject(forEntity: "Entity" into: managedObjectContext)` is provided.

In my application, the code below does the job of creating a new entry in CoreData (I can see because the `NSFetchedResultsController` provides the results). Why does my code work, what is my code actually doing differently from `insertNewObject(forEntity: "Entity" into: managedObjectContext)` and should I actually just be using `insertNewObject(forEntity: "Entity" into: managedObjectContext)?`

```
if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {

            // I am creating an instance of both the food and restaurant from the Food and Restaurant Managed Objects.
            foodEntry = FoodManagedObject(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            restaurantEntry = RestaurantsManagedObject(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)

            // I am firstly setting the name to the nameTextField. That's easy.
            foodEntry.nameOfFood = foodNameTextField.text
            foodEntry.type = restaurantTypeTextField.text
            // I am then setting the restaurant Name using the restaurnt Managed Object and then assigning the foodEntry.restaurant (the relationship) to the entry. This is a trick from Envylope and is what got the restaurantName to display on the Timeline. The same is done for the address.
            restaurantEntry.nameOfRestaurant = restaurantNameTextField.text
            restaurantEntry.address = restaurantLocationTextField.text
            foodEntry.restaurant = restaurantEntry
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38459233/5461400

Comment: try this its help

Comment: Hi, sorry - that's not helpful fully. I need something in Swift and I want to actually understand the procedures, etc as well.

Comment: Okay i will updating into swift with more description.

Comment: https://youtu.be/DkTOvM23i0Q try this to understand.

Comment: @anitsbajaj Check update answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38459233/5461400

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete and Update Data in Core Data in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458195/delete-and-update-data-in-core-data-in-ios)

Comment: Thank you @HarshalValanda - I appreciate your work. The video helped, but I have just updated the question to ask a question. Please could I ask you to provide that information on helping me understand?