# In Core Data, how to do `if exists update else insert` in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new in core data. i just want to check if a record exists in core data then update else insert. i can insert, fetch delete data but unable to update. Here is my piece of code

```
var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var user = [Users]()
func insertData() {

    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)//entity(forEntityName: "Users", in: context)
    newUser.setValue("chatt", forKey: "name")
    newUser.setValue("100", forKey: "balance")
    newUser.setValue("123", forKey: "user_id")
    do {

        try context.save()

    } catch {

        print("Failed saving")
    } 
}
```

Please help me with the update code snippet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38459233/5461400

Comment: You can reference my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089530/4079505)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this :

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userName = %@", userName)

if let fetchResults = appDel.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject] {
    if fetchResults.count != 0 {
        // update
        var managedObject = fetchResults[0]
        managedObject.setValue(accessToken, forKey: "accessToken")

        context.save(nil)
    } else {
        //insert as new data
    }
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Sir, it is showing NSFetchRequestResults has no member 'count'

Comment: errr.. what is access token here?

Comment: @chitgoks it is a value for the accessToken attribute of the users entity,