# Core Data Cocoa Mac OS delete object Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, object, core-data

I have a menu displaying files that are stored in a Core Data model. I'm able to add a new object to the model and display it on the menu. Now, I would like to delete one file from the menu when right clicking on it and choose delete, everything I tried didn't work so far:

```
- (IBAction)RemoveSelectedFile:(id)sender {
    if ([((NSMenuItem *)sender).menu isEqual:self.fileRecordContextMenu]) {

        // get the indices that have been clicked on
        NSIndexSet * indices = [self _indexesToProcessForContextMenuForTable:self.fileRecordsTable];
        ClassFileRecord * fileRecord = (self.document && self.document.fileRecordsController && self.document.fileRecordsController.arrangedObjects && indices && indices.count > 0) ? [self.document.fileRecordsController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:indices.firstIndex] : nil;

        if (fileRecord) {

            // Path to the file
            NSString * u = fileRecord.sourceFilePath;

            if (u) {
                // Delete Object

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I found an easy solution using the NSArrayController:

```
 NSArray * selectedObjects = self.fileRecordsController.selectedObjects;
[self.fileRecordsController removeObjects:selectedObjects];
```

Comment: What did you try. "How do I delete an object from Core Data" has been asked many times.

Comment: As I said, I tried many things: meaning I've looked on the internet and tried them.. but without success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete object in Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039575/delete-object-in-core-data)

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext has a method for this purpose. Did you try it? If it didn't work, what specifically went wrong? Saying "didn't work" is not a useful question.

Comment: See my update, thanks!